# ajax request return value not picked up by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

When i try:

```
$.post("http://mysite.com/myscript.php",{ email:$('#emailRegister').val(),password:$('#passwordRegister').val()} ,function(data){
if(data=='yes')
{
  alert("yes", data);
}
else 
{
  alert("not yes", data);
}
});
```

I get: "not yes yes", what actually should be "yes yes". My php part adds a user to a database and returns "yes" when the user is added (which works).

In another part of my script, I use the same technique, but there it works just fine.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong? If its necessary, here's more code (I'm developping an iOs app using PhoneGap):

```
$("#register_form").submit(function(){
        if(isEmail($("#emailRegister").val())){
             if($("#passwordRegister").val() == $("#repeatPassword").val()){
                 $.post("http://mysite.com/myscript.php",{ email:$('#emailRegister').val(),password:$('#passwordRegister').val()} ,function(data)
                        {
                        if(data=='yes')
                        {
                        alert("yesss ",data);
                                localStorage.setItem("email", $('#emailRegister').val()); //saves to the database, key/value
                                localStorage.setItem("password", $('#passwordRegister').val()); //saves to the database, key/value
                                $.mobile.changePage($("#checkPage"),{ transition: "flip"});
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                        });
             }
             else{
                alert("The passwords do not match!");
             }
         }
         else
         {
            navigator.notification.alert('Please enter a valid emailadres. This adress will be used in several years to send your pictures',null,"Invalid email");

         }
         return false; //not to post the  form physically
    });
```

Comment: Well .. do `console.log()` and see what it contains.

Comment: It contains "yes", but my if statement doesn't think 'yes' == 'yes'

Comment: did you make sure that it is not actually `'  yes '` ?

Comment: 2012-06-09 21:21:28.735 myProject[9025:13403] [INFO] yes

Comment: Is it possible that another piece of my page has errors, and that that is the reason for the error? Because is don't think there is something wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the alert actually says "not yes yes" then the only possibility is that the data variable contains something that looks like "yes" in the alert but actually is subtly different from "yes" (by maybe containing a space or a linefeed character).

Instead of `if (data=="yes")` try `if (data.match(/yes/))`.